# override operations in dask for getitem

Tags: python, dask

Is there a way to override certain operations.

```
import dask
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((10,10))
a = dask.delayed(lambda x : x*2)(a)
```

I would like `a[0]` to return a number (instead of having to call `a[0].compute()`).
Is this possible?

The context is that I would like to have a series of images (3D array), and run operations like:

```
imgs2 = imgs - 1
imgs3 = imgs*mask
```

and then have an operation like `imgs3[0]` explicitly run `imgs3[0].compute()`.

However, I see many drawbacks with this method now and I would like to remove this post. For one is this is quite limiting. Indexing things like `imgs3[:,:, 10]` (all columns) may also have to end up with a computed result.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine for me

```
In [1]: import dask
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: a = np.zeros((10,10))
   ...: a = dask.delayed(lambda x : x*2)(a)
   ...: 

In [2]: a[0]
Out[2]: Delayed('getitem-4eccd4e43153cac99d8e6d280cc1ad9c')

In [3]: a[0].compute()
Out[3]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: I meant to ask if one could define `getitem` to implicitly assume that the dask array be computed. So `a[0]` would imply `a[0].compute()`. I have edited my text. However, I have seen many problems with this and would like to retract this question. Please let me know if you disagree (with the retraction)

Comment: Not at all, that seems like magic.  The right way to do this might be to make your own subclass of Delayed.